# Getting unexpected end of input for the following snippet of code

Tags: json, getjson

I'm getting error `unexpected end of input` for the following snippet of code.

```
$.getJSON("/json/cats.json", function(json) {
        $(".message").html(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Comment: You dint close the function properly. Should be `});` at the end

Comment: God, just noticed that this was asked months before!!! Why are you guys editing this and pulling this up again in the stack???